# How to show <br> tag in input value

Tags: php, html, jquery-ui, input

I want to show my value in input with some style like `<br>` and `<b>` tags and i wouldn't use  `<textarea>` because i am using **jquery easy ui** for formatting my forms.
when

**i try**:

```
<input class="easyui-textbox" data-options="multiline:true" 
style="height:100px; width:250px" name="edu" 
value="a<br>b">
```

Its show : `a<br>b`

**i try this** :

```
<input class="easyui-textbox" data-options="multiline:true" 
style="height:100px; width:250px" name="edu" 
value="a&lt;br /&gt;b">
```

and i see same result.

help me. thanks

Comment: You style it with css not html tags, thats only to give it definition

Answer (score 0):

Usually textarea is used for rendering multiline elements, but since I'm sure internally easy-ui uses it to render multiline textboxes, you can just do:

```
<input ... value="a \n b">
```

...or other variations \r or \r\n.

Comment: use textarea for this

Answer (score 0):

You could use `contenteditable` on a div.

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vn2wxLwn/1/

And it works in all major browsers http://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable